# Laravel 4 - Queueing a cookie forever

Tags: cookies, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, is there a way to set a *queue* a cookie that last forever?

Basically I want to mix the functionality of:

```
Cookie:queue()
```

and

```
Cookie:forever()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, 2628000)
```

If you look at the `Cookie::forever()` code, it defines "forever" as `2628000` (five years)

Comment: So it is pseudo-forever? I see! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

```
 Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever($name, $value));
 return $response;
```

or

```
$response = Response('hello');
$response->withCookie(Cookie::forever($name, $value));
return $response;
```